# MySQL query to get count of current month and last month to get percentage of growth

Tags: mysql

What im trying to achieve is to get the current count and last month count so i can do a formula to get the growth percentage

```
(CountCurrent - CountLastMonth) / CountLastMonth
```

My table has the following fields

```
activity, upload_date
```

This is the query im trying now.

```
SELECT  
        Y.CurrentMonth,     Y.CountCurrent,
        Z.LastMonth,  Z.CountLastMonth


 FROM 
        (SELECT
        upload_date,
        activity,
            DATE_FORMAT(upload_date,'%M %Y') AS CurrentMonth, 
        COUNT(activity) AS CountCurrent
            FROM appmaster
            WHERE activity = 'com.google.test'
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(upload_date,'%m%y')) 
    Y INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
        activity,
        DATE_FORMAT(upload_date,'%M %Y') AS CurrentMonth2, 
            DATE_FORMAT(upload_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%M %Y') AS LastMonth, 
            COUNT(activity) AS CountLastMonth
        FROM appmaster
        WHERE activity = 'com.google.test'
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(upload_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%m%y'))
    Z ON Z.CurrentMonth2 = Y.CurrentMonth 

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(upload_date,'%Y%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(upload_date,'%Y%m')
```

My CurrentMonth, CountCurrent and LastMonth work fine. But the CountLastMonth is coming out the same as CountCurrent.

I was trying this before and it would give me everything but the CountLastMonth

```
SELECT b.CurrentMonth, sum(b.CountCurrent), b.LastMonth
FROM (SELECT DATE(a.upload_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS LastMonth, DATE(a.upload_date) AS CurrentMonth, COUNT(a.activity) AS CountCurrent 
FROM appmaster a WHERE a.activity = 'com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox'
group BY MONTH(a.upload_date)) AS b

group BY MONTH(b.CurrentMonth)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No temporary table required:

```
SELECT
    a.ym,
    CASE @totals
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (a.totals - @totals) / @totals
    END increment,
    @totals := a.totals totals
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM upload_date) ym,
        COUNT(1) AS totals
    FROM
        appmaster
    WHERE
        activity = 'com.google.test'
    GROUP BY ym -- no ORDER BY required
    ) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @totals := 0) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a simpler way to do this, using a little trick with user variables.

First, you need to write a query that groups your data by month; I'll store it in a temp table to ease things a bit:

```
drop table if exists temp_count;
create temporary table temp_count
select last_day(upload_date) as month -- A little trick to get 
                                      -- the last day of the month
     , count(activity) as count_current
     -- Add any other fields or expressions you need
from app_master
-- Add the needed joins
-- Include any WHERE conditions here
group by last_day(upload_date);
-- Let's add an index to this temp table... add any indexes you may need
alter table temp_count
    add index idx_month(month);
```

And now, let's use this temp table to get what you need:

```
select a.month
     , @count_last as count_last    -- This is the value of the user variable
                                    -- before reassigning it
     , (a.count_current - @count_last) / @count_last as increment
     , @count_last := a.count_current -- Here the variable is updated with the
                                      -- current value
from 
    (   -- This subquery is used to initialize the user variable
        select @count_last := 0
    ) as init
    , temp_count as a
-- It's important to order the data, otherwise God knows what may happen ;)
order by a.month;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well explained but other answer seemed to simply much better.

Comment: @Bignadad :) indeed... However, for more complex tasks, temp tables are a useful resource (a convenient "divide-and-conquer" tool that may help you in the future)

Answer (score 0):

Revenue growth over each month - This is based on the [answer provided by Barranka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982400/mysql-query-to-get-count-of-current-month-and-last-month-to-get-percentage-of-gr#25982626) but it is suitable for Monthly revenue growth:

```
 SELECT
  a.YM,
  CASE @Revenue
          WHEN 0 THEN 0
          ELSE (a.Revenue - @Revenue) / @Revenue
      END Increment,
      @Revenue := a.Revenue Revenue
     FROM
       (
        SELECT
        LEFT(payment_date, 7) YM,
        SUM(amount) AS Revenue -- Toatl is SUM of Amount
         FROM
          payment

      GROUP BY YM -- no ORDER BY required
       ) a
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Revenue := 0) x
 ;


SELECT
    a.YM,
    CASE @Revenue
      WHEN 0 THEN 0
      ELSE (a.Revenue - @Revenue) / @Revenue
 END Increment,
  @Revenue := a.Revenue Revenue
    FROM
 (
 SELECT
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM payment_date) YM,
      SUM(amount) AS Revenue
 FROM
      payment

 GROUP BY YM -- no ORDER BY required
 ) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Revenue := 0) x
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            #Rental number Growth per month -- This is the example for monthly growth where "Total count of activity per month" is concerned -- This answer was developed based on Barranka answer and credit goes to him.
        SELECT
            a.YM,
            CASE @Num_of_Rentals
                WHEN 0 THEN 0
                ELSE (a.Num_of_Rentals - @Num_of_Rentals) / @Num_of_Rentals
            END increment,
            @Num_of_Rentals := a.Num_of_Rentals Num_of_Rentals
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                LEFT(rental_date,7) YM,
                COUNT(rental_id) AS Num_of_Rentals
            FROM
                rental
                GROUP BY ym -- no ORDER BY required
            ) a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Num_of_Rentals := 0) x;

        -- OR
        SELECT
            a.YM,
            CASE @Num_of_Rentals
                WHEN 0 THEN 0
                ELSE (a.Num_of_Rentals - @Num_of_Rentals) / @Num_of_Rentals
            END increment,
            @Num_of_Rentals := a.Num_of_Rentals Num_of_Rentals
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                LEFT(rental_date,7) YM,
                COUNT(1) AS Num_of_Rentals
            FROM
                rental
                GROUP BY ym -- no ORDER BY required
            ) a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Num_of_Rentals := 0) x;
```